# how to make href random button go to ID tag

Tags: css

im creating a random link href button, i want to make button that can go to different ID.

```html
<a href="#comment">this one is working</a>
```

```js
function randomlinks(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="#commentsection"
    links[1]="/#commentsection"
    links[2]="http://www.example.com/#commentsection"

 
    window.location=links[myrandom]
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="button" value="Random ID" onClick="randomlinks()">
</form>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: im trying to make href button go to ID, example when i click the button it goes to #Div1, but the code above reload my page and show link not found.

Comment: @Reivax Your example doesn't go to three different fragment identifiers, but to the same fragment identifiers in three different URLs.